# how to show that $\int_A f \, d\mu =\mu(A) \int_X f \, d\mu$ when $\mu(E\cap A)=\mu(E) \mu(A)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space and there exists a set $A\in M$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ such that $\mu(E\cap A)=\mu(E) \mu(A)$ of all $E\in M$.

I want to show that $\int_A f \, d\mu =\mu(A) \int_X f \, d\mu$. for all $f \in L^1$

I know the condition $\mu(E\cap A)=\mu(E) \mu(A)$ will tell us the space is finite. and I was only able to prove that its true for simple function that is $f=\chi_E$.

Update:- this solution was based on the comments of Michael

$$\int_X f \, d\mu =\int_A f \, d\mu+ \int_{A^c} f d\mu$$
we have two case:-

- When $\mu(A)=0$ and $\mu(A^c)=\mu(X)$ then:-

$$\int_A f d\mu=0=0\times \int_{X} f d\mu$$

1. When $\mu(A)=1=\mu(X)$ and $\mu(A^c)=0$ then:-
   $$ 1\times \int_X f \, d\mu =\int_A f \, d\mu+0$$

Is this right now?
Note:- 
this solution depend on the fact that integral over null set is zero.

Comment: If you have the result for characteristic functions, then you can deduce it for linear combinations of those, and then for $L^1$ limits of such linear combinations.

Comment: Yes.I thought about that, and you are right its work,but my question is now,can we work directly on the function on $L^1$ instead of step by step moving up. thanks

Comment: Try applying $\mu(E \cap A) = \mu(E)\mu(A)$ to $E=A$ and $E=A^c$.

Comment: You could also use $\int_X f\,d\mu = \int_0^\infty \mu(\{x\in X\colon f(x) > y\}) \,dy$, if you have that fact available to you (or prove it yourself).

Comment: @GregMartin its look like Fubini's theorem to me.

Comment: @Michael based on your comment, either $\mu(A)=\mu(X)=1$ or $\mu(A^c)=\mu(X)=1$.

Comment: How do you get the "or $\mu(A^c)=1$" part?

Comment: the measure of $A$ is either one or zero, in case zero then we have $\mu(X)=\mu(A)+\mu(A^c)$ hence $\mu(X)=\mu(A^c)$ I was wrong in say its one.sorry

Comment: What if $M$ is the interval $[0,2]$ and $A$ is the single point $0$.  Then clearly $\mu(A^c) \neq 1$.

Comment: Yeah.  Our last comments crossed.  =)

Comment: @Michael Finally I do something based on your beautiful comment.

Comment: Yes, as you said, the integral over the measure-0 set is 0.